# String metric in Elastic Search - Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to visualize tests in Kibana using elastic search.

Specifically What I wanted to do, is send in the Json, a field named "outcome", which can be passed, failed, or skipped, along with each test name (or maybe in one string).

Then, based on the value of that `outcome` field, i'd like to show/not show the error message (Which chould be None in case the test passed or skipped), in a table for example, next to the name of the test.

If someone understood me, how can I achieve such behavior?
I'd be happy to see any example, even a simple one, for example people, and gender column next to them - man/woman. If it's a man, also show it's height, for example, which is also passed as a field.

I know my question isn't structured well and i'd be happy to give any clarifications. I'm just helpless, I can't figure out how to do it.